# RxSwift error using Sort on Variable<[Element]>

Tags: io, ios10, rx-swift

I have a array like this:

```
    var arrayPoints:Variable<[Point]>?
```

Later the user can sort the listlike this:

```
  func orderPointsByDistance(){
       self.arrayPoints?.value.sort{ $0.stringDistance.compare($1.stringDistance) == .orderedAscending  }
  }
```

However i am receiving this error:

```
fatal error: Executing on backgound thread.
Please use MainScheduler.instance.schedule to schedule work on main thread.: file /Users/dasilvans/Desktop/GeoPlay/Pods/RxSwift/RxSwift/Rx.swift, line 23
```

In a way I perceive the error, but do not know how to solve it.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this i think you are blocking the rx when doing that

```
let stuff = Array(self.arrayPoints?.value)
stuff.sort{ $0.stringDistance.compare($1.stringDistance) == .orderedAscending  }
self.arrayPoints?.value = stuff
```

or it is a matter of

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

}
```

Comment: you are correct. I was calling the method in a async task. Thanks